# Using onClick on Bootstrap Dropdown 'option' - React hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have create a Bootstrap Dropdown menu.
I would like to click on one of the dropdown `options` and, once clicked, performed an action.
However, it seems that the `options` does not handle the `onClick` function.

```
function MyDropdown(previousSearch) {

    function handleClick() {
        console.log("testestest")
    }

    return(
        <div>

            <Form.Group controlId="exampleForm.ControlSelect2">
                <Form.Control as="select" style={{border: "none", outline: "none", boxShadow: "none"}}>
                    {previousSearch.previousSearch["myPreviousSearch"].map(function(preSearch, index){
                        return (
                            <option
                                style={{border: "none"}}
                                onClick={handleClick}
                            >
                                {preSearch}
                            </option>
                        )
                    })}
                </Form.Control>
            </Form.Group>

        </div>
    )

}

export default MyDropdown
```

I want to `console.log("testtest")`once the user click one of the options in the dropdown **but** nothing happens.

I tried adding a `<select>` and give the ònClick`to it, but nothing changes.

[image: Dropdown]

Comment: did you onChange on <select> element? (instead of onClick)

Comment: Yes, I tried that too with little success